# Editing colors in Blender for vibrance and saturation

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, texture-painting, color

Is there a way within Blender to edit colors, like Photoshop, using variables such as vibrance and saturation?

For example:
[image]
[image]
The image below is an photoshopped version of the first image, with vibrance +80 and saturation +2.
Is it possible to boost colors within Blender, without any post processing methods? (Such as those involving external programs, e.g. Photoshop)

Comment: related, https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/how-can-i-cast-artificially-darker-shadows https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55231/what-is-the-the-asc-cdl-node

Answer (score 5):

Besides the postproduction options outlined in other answers, you can be intentional on how you use the elements instead of resorting to "*fixing in post*". **You do have absolute control** on the quality of the scene by careful crafting of the materials used and the lighting of the scene, without having to resort to additional effects.
If you want more saturated colors... use more saturated colors, or darker colors, in the shaders those are the ones that determine the color of an object in the scene, you have total control on how objects reflect light or how shiny they are. Also make sure that the intensity, and quality, of your lights is not making the objects too bright, and that is helping you get what you want.

Also play a bit with the different looks on the color management section. A higher contrast might be useful.

[image]

Read **both answers** on the following link very carefully:

[Desaturated red when rendered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/120668/desaturated-red-when-rendered)

And read the whole page (comments and answers) here:

[How can I get more saturated colors when I render?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96445/how-can-i-get-more-saturated-colors-when-i-render)

To understand the relationship between brightness and saturation on the *filmic* color transform read this as well:

[Render with a wider dynamic range in cycles to produce photorealistic looking images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46825/render-with-a-wider-dynamic-range-in-cycles-to-produce-photorealistic-looking-im)

Answer (score 4):

Blender's compositor has nodes that are analogous to controls commonly found in post-processing applications, and can separate color into several spaces.  Some examples:

[image]

Blender's compositor is not very performant compared to other applications, but it can be made much better by checking a few options in the N-panel.

[image]

You can set the edit quality level for better/quicker visualization, and check the box for OpenCL to enable GPU calculations.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have several ways to adjust the color balance :

- In your ***3D View***, you can tweak the materials to make sure that they are as close as possible to what you want. For example if you mix your *Diffuse* with a bit of *Emission* you can make sure that you'll have colors that will less depend on your lighting (but of course the shadows will tend to disappear). It's the first thing to do in my opinion.
- As Allen Simpson says, you can use the ***Compositor***, you have a series of nodes that can correct your colors (*Hue Saturation Value*, *RGB Curves*, etc...), and it will affect the layers you want.
- You can give some ajustments in the ***Video Sequencer*** : Import your image(s) or movie(s), select the strip you want, open the N panel on the right, give your strip a modifier *Color Balance* or *Bright/Contrast*, etc...