# Does anyone know of a material node group (not compositing) that emulates Photoshops "Vibrance" control?

Tags: node-editor, color, shader-nodes

[Here](https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/analyzing-photoshop-vibrance-and-saturation/) is an article that breaks down what Vibrance is actually doing under the hood. The TL;DR version is:

> (Vibrance) Adjusts the saturation so that clipping is minimized as colors approach full saturation. This setting changes the saturation of all lower-saturated colors with less effect on the higher-saturated colors. Vibrance also prevents skin tones from becoming oversaturated.

The images below demonstrate:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

I am looking for any kind of node group that works in the shader editor (not compositor) that does exactly this.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not really.  Vibrance is something that can only be determined in the compositor, because it depends on how light strikes the surface. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/207644/editing-colors-in-blender-for-vibrance-and-saturation is a good starting point for understanding what you can and can't do on the topic.

Comment: @MartyFouts The hypothetical nodegroup I am talking about would be to color correct an image texture in the shader editor. I know it's possible because I found one vibrance group [here](https://blendermarket.com/products/bvfx-nodes). Since it was a compositing nodegroup I re-implemented it as a shader nodegroup - and it worked fine. The only issue is that you can't really push it too far; the effect is very subtle. 

TL;DR: It's absolutely possible to do.

Comment: You can approximate the effect using RGB curves but you have to tune the curves for every separate image.  I imagine it would be better to color correct the image in an image editing program that has the whole suite of tools available.