# Is there a way to use lighting in a scene with an image texture without changing any of the colors in the image? (Eevee)

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting

I am new to Blender and I'm trying to put this thing into a video, but the final render in the video has different colors than the regular image because of a light source. Is there a rendering method or a way to prevent colors from changing from a light source?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't find a duplicate, but I'm sure similar enough questions have been asked.

> [...] use lightning [...] without changing [...] colors in the image

Changing colors of a texture is called [shading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shading):

> **Shading** refers to the depiction of depth perception in 3D models (within the field of 3D computer graphics) or illustrations (in visual art) by varying the level of darkness. Shading tries to approximate local behavior of light on the object's surface [...]

Therefore if you want to remove such behavior, you want a *shadeless* material, which you achieve by removing a shader:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The concept "color" of most peopel is a bit unspecific. Color splits in [Chromaticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromaticity) and Luminance. If you light something brighter you increas its Luminance therefor changing its Color.

1. As mentioned in the Answer about Shading... you can avoid this using a Shadeless Material.
2. Aditionaly in the Render stage your Colors go through a [Color Transform](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html).
3. And Finaly your input texture and Saved Output File have a [Color Space](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144854/blender-2-8-image-texture-node-and-color-space?noredirect=1&lq=1).

This ar all complex topics on there own... and you have to get everything right if you want the same "color" out .. as you put in... I wish you a nice journey:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92301/47253

Answer (score 0):

You can use an Emission Shader for your image object. Eevee doesnt support shader based lighting, so you only get the absolute values of your image.