# What is the most efficient way to match green screen footage to a Blender scene?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I have green screen footage I chroma keyed, color corrected, and exported in DaVinci Resolve. I matched it to a still image of a Blender scene *(Cycles)*.

When I import the footage into the actual Blender scene *(Image as Plane)*, the footage no longer has the proper color because Cycles affects the light of the plane. So it's always either too bright or too dark depending on how I import it *(Principled, Shadeless, or Emit)*.

I know I can add some extra lights to a collection, move them around, and turn on/off to make it look proper, but that's a bunch of extra steps and I'll bet there's a smarter way.

What would you do?

Comment: Read https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/146606/33589 Short answer, set your image texture color space to RAW

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work. Instead, that makes it look more like RAW footage: very flat, low contrast and low saturation. Though you gave me an idea... I know that the gamma from my camera to my editor had to be converted from I think linear into something else so it was easier to view with the LUT in the editor (or else it's very dark)... Which makes me think maybe Blender does something similar without telling us, and there might be a node I can use to convert it back... Will do some research on nodes I've never used before.