# Difference between Color Space > Non-Color and Linear for normal maps

Tags: normal-map

I've opened a normal map in my *Image Texture*, the node was set to *Color Space > Linear*, and it doesn't seem to make any difference with *Non-Color*. Without going into too many details, can someone confirm? Thanks:

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: This looks like a discution type of question from the main post. From the Title itself look like something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/144854/blender-2-8-image-texture-node-and-color-space Change your light source to see the difference, put a copy side by side and change the color space for one

Comment: thanks Emir but the post doesn't really answer, it says normal maps should be Non-Color, ok that's what I've always been told but Linear doesn't seem to make any difference?!?

Comment: Is it possible that your normal map was already in the linear color space, and that's why you didn't see any noticeable difference between the "Non-Color" and "Linear" color space settings?

Comment: the image i share is just an example, in my case I just created a black image (32 bit float), baked a normal map, and used it as a normal map. Then I noticed that the Image Texture was set to Linear. When I switched it to Non-Color it didn't seem to change anything, therefore my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases they are essentially the same and so is Raw. My tests showed no difference between the three. You have to make sure there is no gamma correction, which is done to improve visible images. The old dogma stems from back in the days when the image texture node did not have linear color space. However, to be on the safe side, I'd suggest you keep using non-color data, because:

Linear:
Blender’s native linear space meaning there is no gamma mapping, using Linear Rec. 709 chromaticities and a D65 white point.

Non-Color and Raw: 
Color space used for images which contains non-color data (e.g. normal maps).

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html#ocio-config

Comment: OK thanks a lot for the answer